# How to subclass Array in JavaScript and override 'length' getter and setter?

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, getter, setter

I am trying to subclass JavaScript array and override 'length' getter and setter. This code is not working - it outputs nothing to the console because getter and setter are not called. How to fix this?

```
class MyArray extends Array {
  get length() {
    console.log('length getter')
    return super.length
  }

  set length(value) {
    console.log('length setter')
    super.length = value
  }
}

const arr = new MyArray()
arr.length = 1
console.log(arr.length)
```

Comment: `length` is an instance property, defining a getter/setter on the prototype won't work

Comment: You cannot override getter and setter for `length`. Also, why would you do that? Do you think it's really required?

Answer (score 1):

`length` is a non-configurable property which is created inside the `Array` constructor (see [here](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-array)). So the only way to override it is to use [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy).

```js
class MyArray extends Array {

    constructor() {
        super()

        return new Proxy(this, {
            get: (target, property, receiver) => {
                if (property === 'length') {
                    console.log('length getter')
                }
                
                return Reflect.get(target, property, receiver)
            },
            set: (target, property, value, receiver) => {
                if (property === 'length') {
                    console.log('length setter')
                }
                
                return Reflect.set(target, property, value, receiver)
            },
        })
        
    }
}
```

Be cautious though - IT CAN DAMAGE THE PERFORMANCE OF YOUR PROGRAM.

Comment: A good point about the performance. Proxifying arrays slows them down especially with long arrays;